# cronjobs under ubuntu php not working

Tags: 14.04, php, cron

I am trying to set up cronjobs to excecute some emailing to clients periodically but I am seeing no output fromm the test I wrote
here  is the crontab line

```
    * * * * * php /var/www/html/pms/notices/test.php
```

and here is the test.php code

```
    <?php
     include(__DIR__ . "/config.php");
     $log_message = 'It works';
        error_log($log_message . "On:" . date("l jS \of F, Y, h:i:s A P") . "\n", 3, ROOT_PATH .'Logs/activity.log');      
    <?
```

I expect  the activity.log file to have 'it works' written to it every minnute  but nothing is.
Could I be doing anything wrong? If yes what is it? or where can I get good tutorial on how to set up cron jobs
I have tried changing my line to

```
   * * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/html/pms/notices/test.php
```

as suggested in another question but that  has not helped

Comment: So the issue is not the cronjob but the script?

Comment: I am new to  cron jobs and don't clearly where the problem is

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen the problem is actually the cronjob and not the script as it runs when I run it manually

Comment: Check permissions is the cronjob writing to a write protected folder!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosent the folders are not write protected at all

Answer (score 1):

The cron runtime environment is different than the interactive environment which is also different from the at/batch environment.

Run this in each of your environments, then compare the files:

```
(echo "=== set ===";set;echo "===env ==="; env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias) >a_different_log
```

I did this, and got:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ ll *.environment
-rw-rw-r-- 1 walt walt  10672 Oct 22 13:59 at.environment
-rw-rw-r-- 1 walt walt  10672 Oct 22 13:57 batch.environment
-rw-rw-r-- 1 walt walt   1031 Oct 22 14:00 cron.environment
-rw-rw-r-- 1 walt walt 126378 Oct 22 13:55 interactive.environment
walt@bat:~(0)$ wc -l *.environment
   238 at.environment
   238 batch.environment
    48 cron.environment
  3642 interactive.environment
```

Some setting in your environment, needed for PHP to work, is not set in the cron environment. You will have to set it manually, or wrap your command in a bash script that sets up the environment.

Comment: Would you tell me how to do that?

Comment: @waltinator already told you the first step: Compare.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the `/usr/bin/php` is not in the `$PATH` for cron. Try a crontjob like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /some/file.php
```

Comment: That was the first attempt I made but did now work